# If each edge of a graph $G=(V,E)$ belongs to exactly one triangle then $|E|=\omicron(n^{2})$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Given $\epsilon > 0$, prove the existence of a $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, if $G=(V,E)$ is a graph on $n > n_\epsilon$ vertices, and each edge of $G$ belongs to exactly one triangle, then $|E| \leq \epsilon n^2$.

My idea is to use the following lemma:

> **Triangle Removal Lemma.** For every $\gamma > 0$, there exists $\delta = \delta(\gamma) >0$ such that for every graph $G$ at least one of the following is true:
>   (A) there exists $F \subset E(G), |F| \leq \gamma v(G)^2$, such that $G - F$ is triangle-free
>   (B) $G$ contains at least $\delta v(G)^3$ triangles

Given a graph $G$ with the stated property, my observation is that the number of triangles in $G$ is $\frac{|E|}{3}$. Set $\gamma = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. If we can define $\delta$ and $n_\epsilon$ so that this number of triangles in $G$ is less than $\delta n^3$, then we would have forced $(B)$ not to occur (and $(A)$ to occur).

The property of $G$ also gives us a set $F \subset E(G)$, $|F| = \frac{|E|}{3}$, such that $G - F$ is triangle free (i.e. we remove an edge from each triangle). And so, since $(A)$ occurs, $\frac{|E|}{3} < \gamma n^2$ and thus $|E| < 3\gamma n^2 = \epsilon n^2$.

I get stuck trying to define $\delta$ and $n_\epsilon$. All I know is that $\frac{|E|}{3} < \delta n^3$, and the self-evident fact that $n_\epsilon$ cannot be whatever we like, since otherwise, with $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small and $|E| \leq \epsilon n^2$, $|E|$ might be $0$. I think there must be some lower bound of $|E|$ that I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $G$ has the property that each edge belongs to exactly one triangle, then any pair of vertices of $G$ may have at most one edge connecting them.

Let $\gamma > 0$ and $\delta$ be its associated $\gamma$.
In order for $(B)$ to be false, you must have $|E|/3 < \delta |V|^3$, or

$$|E| < 3\delta |V|^3.\tag{1}$$

In light of the observation, we must have $|E| \leqslant \binom{|V|}2$.
Now, given $\delta$, it's easy to see that for $|V|$ large enough we have
$\binom{|V|}2 < 3\delta |V|^3,$ and hence $(1)$ must hold.

We have established then there is $n_\delta\in \Bbb N$ large enough for which $(A)$ must be true.
In this case, $|E|/3 < \gamma |V|^2 \implies |E| < 3\gamma |V|^2$.
But this is basically what we want.

Given $\epsilon$, take $\gamma = \epsilon/3$.
Observe that

- $\gamma$ is given in terms of $\epsilon$;
- From the lemma, we may obtain $\delta$ in terms of $\gamma$; and
- From our observation above, we may obtain $n_\delta$ in terms of $\delta$.

It follows that $n_\delta$ may be given in terms of $\epsilon$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Regarding your formula for $T$, wouldn't this be a counter-example? https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a0339c3a69ce4c48e567955d18f44d26 (the vertices of the graph are the corners of the two squares)

Comment: Given a polygon with $m$ sides, for $m$ large enough, we can create a graph on $2m$ vertices with more triangles than your formula suggests. Combining the $m$ sides of the polygon with $m$ vertices to create $m$ triangles (we'd have something like a polygon with "spikes"). Now we can build extra triangles "inside" the polygon from the original $m$ vertices, as long as the portion of the polygon between two vertices of a new triangle contains at least two vertices.

Comment: You are right. In this way, you could get with $18$ vertices a total of $12$ triangles. This construction still has a linear bound on $|V|$, but of course it means the proof is no bueno. We can use a crude estimate to get the job done though. I got carried away with trying to get sharp bounds.

Comment: See the edit; there's a simple, crude bound that works.

Comment: It's a very crude bound indeed! Also I had a hunch that the closed form of one of the parameters might not be obtainable, at least with the tool that we have. Regarding your second to last bullet point, is there anything else we can say about $\delta$?

Comment: This is not my specialty; I admit I only took advantage of the lemma you provided.